# I made confuse about Navigation between navigateUpTo() and using Intent

Tags: android, navigation

Sorry for my foolish and I want to ask for two questions, but there are related.

After I read the document in Google:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html
I still don't understand somethings.

I want to handle Up or (Home) button to navigating to just one level parent screen:

Code a:

```
Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MyParentActivity.class);
NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
return true;
```

And code b:

```
Intent parentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MyParentActivity.class);
parentActivityIntent.addFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
finish();
return true;
```

Both codes are placed in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) event handler.

What is the difference about that?

My second question is, actually I want to navigate as following situation:
a) I have a Menu screen, let say it is a main screen.
b) Menu screen can navigates to Form screen to get information from user.
c) Menu screen can also navigates to Report screen to show report to user.

After user completed the Form screen, I want to navigate the screen directly to Report screen, but don't want the Menu screen show up a little bit second because of route through it.

It somethings like that a case of Lateral Navigation but I am not sure.

Hope someone help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two snippets is in the behavior defined by the flags.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP:
> If set, and the activity being launched is
> already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new
> instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it
> will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top)
> old activity as a new Intent.
>
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
> If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.

NavUtils is a wrapper designed to make it easier to implement the home button in a way that's consistent with what people expect across different versions of Android.  If you look at the source, on pre-jellybean devices it will use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag, but *NOT* the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.  On Jellybean devices, it doesn't use either flag.

For your second question (going straight from the form to the report activity), when the user is done with the form in the Form activity, create an intent to the Report activity and call startActivity.  There's no reason to go back through the home activity.

Comment: Thanks Alexander.

For my second question, I don't want user press Back button (on device) to navigate back to the Form activity. I just want user back to Menu activity. How can I do that?

Comment: In the Form Activity, call finish() right after you call startActivity(ReportActivity.class).

Comment: I get it. So for my first question. If I want the app can run on API 8 to API 13, which method I should use to do Up navigation?

Comment: Definitely use NavUtils for home/up icon behavior.  However, since the ActionBar (and that home/up icon) didn't exist until API 11, that home/up icon won't exist on API 8,9, or 10 devices.

Comment: I am using Sherlock library, work with Intent.addFlags way seems quite well. I just worry about some issue if it is not a most suitable situation for the method.